# react native: What is the way to change the alert to modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, modal-dialog

What is the way to change the alert to modal?
In my example I tried to make the change but it says that it does not know `item.codeName` and also `setModalVisible`, `modalVisible` .
I would be happy to support the issue

```
function firstButton(item) {
    Alert.alert({item.codeName},
      [{ text: 'ok, style: 'cancel', onPress: async () => { } }],
      { cancelable: false });
  }
```

to this modal:

```
 function firstButton(item) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
            <Modal animationType="slide" transparent={true} visible={modalVisible}>
                <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                    <View style={styles.modalView}>
                        <Text style={styles.modalText}>
                            {item.codeName}
                        </Text>

                        <View
                            style={{
                                flexDirection: 'row',
                                justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                                alignContent: 'space-between',
                            }}
                        >
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                                onPress={() => {
                                    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                                }}
                            >
                                <View style={{ top: 20, marginHorizontal: 10 }}>
                                    <LinearGradient
                                        colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}
                                        style={{
                                            borderRadius: 40,
                                            elevation: 10,
                                            paddingHorizontal: 40,
                                            paddingVertical: 10,
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>ok</Text>
                                    </LinearGradient>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                                onPress={() => {
                                    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                                }}
                            >
                                <View style={{ top: 20, marginHorizontal: 10 }}>
                                    <LinearGradient
                                        colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}
                                        style={{
                                            borderRadius: 40,
                                            elevation: 10,
                                            paddingHorizontal: 40,
                                            paddingVertical: 10,
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>cancel</Text>
                                    </LinearGradient>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For `modalVisible` and `setModalVisible` you need to define a react state, like -

> For functional components

```
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = React.useState(false);
```

Then change the value of `modalVisible` to `true` using `setModalVisible` when you want your modal to be displayed on the screen.

For `item.codeName` - Please share `item` structure. However, if you are using `firstButton` as a component then destructure your prop, use `function firstButton({item})` instead otherwise it should work fine.

Comment: i did as u said but it gives an error :
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.codeName')

Comment: @MariaJ, it would be helpful if you show us how u call the firstButton. If it doesn't recognise item, the probably you didn't pass anything to firstButton.

Comment: I agree with @garjted .

Comment: ok u can see this snack :
https://snack.expo.io/@roei133/4b2e89